# Joomla Virtuemart - Identify new DB records - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, virtuemart

I am trying to write some code which i will execute from a cron job daily, which will email me the product_sku field from #__virtuemart_products where the date is today. I have started by just trying to access the data through the following code:

```
    <?php 

// Get a db connection.
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

// Create a new query object.
$query = $db->getQuery(true);

// Select all records from the user profile table where key begins with "custom.".
// Order it by the ordering field.
$query->select($db->quoteName(array('product_sku')));
$query->from($db->quoteName('#__virtuemart_products'));
//$query->where($db->quoteName('profile_key') . ' LIKE '. $db->quote('\'custom.%\''));
$query->where($db->quoteName (DATE_FORMAT('created_on', '%Y-%m-%d')) = CURDATE();
$query->order('ordering ASC');

// Reset the query using our newly populated query object.
$db->setQuery($query);

// Load the results as a list of stdClass objects (see later for more options on retrieving data).
$results = $db->loadObjectList();

$db->setQuery($query);
$row = $db->loadRow();
print_r($row);
?>
```

I have been working with joomla for quite some time, but this is the first time that i have tried to write something from scratch. When i run this i get a 500 error, and i'm not sure where to start to try and fix it? Any help would be most appreciated.

Best Regards
Donna

Comment: Thank you :) I have signed up.